# Eureka Server peer Replication over mTLS

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

Is it possible to configure Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka Server over mTLS.
I have a Eureka Server in which I have enable mTLS ( I have set server.ssl.clientAuth=need ) and provided my custom CA as truststore.

For my Eureka clients applications I am able to register my application to Eureka Server over mTLS without any issue. And for DiscoverClient is my EurekaServer I have configured `Jersey3DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs` and so I am able to register my Eureka Server as a Eureka Client mTLS.

I am facing issues while trying to while Replicating to Peer Nodes over mTLS via `Jersey3ReplicationClient` . Initially I was getting "PKIX path building failed" error. For Which I have update my JVM cacerts truststore.
Now I am getting "bad_certificate"

Below is the SSL Handshake debug log. I have only included the relevant part.
I can see while Replicating to Peer Nodes.
Server Certificate is produced, Which then trusted by the `Jersey3ReplicationClient` ( Because I added the issuing CA Certificate to JVM Truststore in JAVA HOME ) . Then I can see the `Jersey3ReplicationClient` is not producing any certificate/key to authenticate it self (`Empty client certificate chain`). As mTLS is enabled, Replication to Peer Nodes is failing.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|04|https-jsse-nio-9080-exec-4|2024-02-03 06:32:42.014 IST|CertificateMessage.java:1172|Consuming client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificate": {
  "certificate_request_context": "",
  "certificate_list": [  
]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|F2|TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-11|2024-02-03 06:32:42.015 IST|SSLCipher.java:2024|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|04|https-jsse-nio-9080-exec-4|2024-02-03 06:32:42.018 IST|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (BAD_CERTIFICATE): Empty client certificate chain (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1188)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:427)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:213)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1719)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)}
```

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|F2|TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-11|2024-02-03 06:32:42.029 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1755|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|F2|TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-11|2024-02-03 06:32:42.029 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1781|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|F2|TaskBatchingWorker-target_localhost-11|2024-02-03 06:32:42.029 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1672|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1509)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:661)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:345)
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.Jersey3ReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(Jersey3ReplicationClient.java:116)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80)
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)}
```

Is there anyway to configure trustore and keystore for the Replication Client like I have configured for the Jersey Discovery Client via `Jersey3DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs`.
My main objectives is to enable mTLS is Eureka Server cluster with Replication enabled, But the Replication Client is not producing any Client Certificate.
I tried to find to update SSLContext for this Jersey Replication Client, but seems there is no straight forward way to do so.
I have also tried using VM arguments like `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` but still the Client Certificate produced by the Jersey Replication Client is empty.
How to achieve this?
My pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

My application.yml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: EUREKA-SERVER

server:
  port: 9080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    keyStore: classpath:keystore/eureka_server_mTLS.p12
    keyStorePassword: mypassword
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: eurekaserver
    clientAuth: need
    trustStore: classpath:truststore/CA_mTLS_Soumyadip.jks
    trustStorePassword: mypassword
    trustStoryType: JKS

  http:
    enabled: false


eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false
    tls:
      trustStore: classpath:truststore/CA_mTLS_Soumyadip.jks
      trustStorePassword: mypassword
      trustStoreType: JKS
      keyStore: classpath:keystore/eureka_server_mTLS.p12
      keyPassword: mypassword
      keyStorePassword: mypassword
      keyAlias: eurekaserver
      enabled: true
      keyStoreType: PKCS12
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://192.168.29.6:9081/eureka/
```

Comment: Did you get this working ? I am also looking for ways to make this work locally, ignoring hostname verification